# Building from Singularity recipes problems

Tags: perl, singularity-container

I am a beginner in Singularity and I would like having help in building from a recipe.

I want to use [`GARM`](http://garm-meta-assem.sourceforge.net/), a genome assemblies reconciliation tool, to reconciliate two genomes I have assembled. Since I am working on a HPC server, I don't have the permissions to install the required perl packages for this tool (which are `Parallel::ForkManager` and `List::MoreUtils`) and R. I found there are two possible solutions for that (and please tell me if I am wrong or if there are other things I can do):

1. install R and perl modules locally (but in this case I should change all the scripts references to them)
2. build a Singularity container containing all the dependencies needed and GARM, since the server has `Singularity 2.6` installed.

I choosen the second solution and decided to use a recipe to build the container, which is the following:

```
Bootstrap: docker

From: ubuntu

%files 
    GARM_0.7.4

%post -c /bin/bash
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y --force-yes perl build-essential cpanminus r-base

    cpanm Parallel::ForkManager List::MoreUtils
    export GARMBIN=/GARM_0.7.4/bin
    export GARMLIB=/GARM_0.7.4/lib
    export MUMBIN=/GARM_0.7.4/MUMmer3.22
    export AMOSBIN=/GARM_0.7.4/amos-3.0.0/bin
    export AMOSLIB=/GARM_0.7.4/amos-3.0.0/lib

%runscript
    exec perl /GARM_0.7.4/GARM.pl
```

where `GARM_0.7.4` is the folder downloaded containing everything the software needs, except R and perl modules.

I use `sudo singularity build garm.simg recipe-garm` to build the container.

Then using `singularity run garm.simg --help` to see if the container works, it comes out this:

```
Can't open perl script "/GARM_0.7.4/GARM.pl": Permission denied
```

Now, even if on the server I cannot use `sudo`, on my PC I tried anyway it with `sudo singularity run garm.simg --help`, and the output is:

```
Empty compile time value given to use lib at /GARM_0.7.4/GARM.pl line 12.
Can't locate GARM_main.pm in @INC (you may need to install the GARM_main module) (@INC contains:  /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /GARM_0.7.4/GARM.pl line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /GARM_0.7.4/GARM.pl line 13.
```

I don't know what is wrong. I can't get if the problem is the garm folder not copied inside the container so that the garm script can't be run, or if there are sintax problem in the recipe and the container does not run the script.

EDIT: added exports as README.txt from the tool suggests, but the situation does not change.

Comment: What's line 12 of GARM.pl, and where is GARM_main.pm?

Comment: It's `use lib "$ENV{GARMLIB}";`. Now I realized I forgot to put the exports in the recipe. I add them and I'll let you know if it works! Thank you I completely missed it!

Comment: Solution #1: How do scripts refer to modules in the code?

Comment: Well, I never used Perl, but according to what says [Perl wiki](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_install_PERL_modules) once packages are installed in local as non-root you have to add to Perl scripts. I interprete that as I have to redirect the package to my local Perl lib. In each script there a `use module_name`, for example `use MoreUtills`.

Comment: I don't think that the exports in your post section will necessarily mean those variables are available in the container. Try adding them as well to the `%environment` section.